# Angular 5 lazy loaded module path overlays each others

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-guards

I have an application with two lazy loading modules.

Main module:

```
const appRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
      path: 'guest',
      loadChildren: 'app/guest-module/guest.module#GuestModule',
    },
    {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: 'app/user-module/user.module#UserModule',
    },
    {path: '**', component: NopageComponent},
  ],
);
```

Child module 1 (GuestModule):

```
  const viewRoutes = RouterModule.forChild([
     {path: 'overview/:reportId', component: HistoryOverviewComponent, canActivate: [GuestAuthGuard]},
  ]);
```

Child module 2 (UserModule):

```
  const viewRoutes = RouterModule.forChild([
     {path: 'overview/:reportId', component: HistoryOverviewComponent, canActivate: [UserAuthGuard]},
  ]);
```

When i route to /guest/overview/1 it always hit to the UserAuthGuard. Is it normal that children routes overlays each other?

Is there a way to distinguish them by configuration rather than changing names?

I use angular 5.2.9 with angular cli 1.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is in

```
{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: 'app/user-module/user.module#UserModule',
},
```

you have to provide a name for that path or add pathMatch: 'full' to avoid redirection to user path, i suggest this:

```
 {
   path: 'guest',
   loadChildren: 'app/guest-module/guest.module#GuestModule',
 },
 {
   path: 'user',
   loadChildren: 'app/user-module/user.module#UserModule',
 },
 {path: '**', component: NopageComponent},
```

or:

```
 {
   path: 'guest',
   loadChildren: 'app/guest-module/guest.module#GuestModule',
 },
 {
   path: '',
   loadChildren: 'app/user-module/user.module#UserModule',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 },
 {path: '**', component: NopageComponent},
```

Comment: Nope i already tried it earlier and it is not working. Looks like something changes in the router path matcher - it is not aware of prefixes defined on the root.

Comment: Second answer is not working too, unfortunately. If I add pathMath: 'full' then angular cannot load any path that is defined in the module.

However your answers lead me to a working solution. If i merge two module and use pathMatch: 'full', then routing is start to work as expecting.

 `const viewRoutes = RouterModule.forChild([
     {path: 'overview/:reportId', component: HistoryOverviewComponent, canActivate: [GuestAuthGuard], pathMatch: 'full'},
     {path: 'guest/overview/:reportId', component: HistoryOverviewComponent, canActivate: [GuestAuthGuard]},
  ]);`

Comment: Merging two lazy loaded module could be use for now, but further down the road I would like to have two separate modules anyway.